# Equivalent term of integration

Tags: integration, functions, numerical-methods

Let $f:[0,3]\to\mathbb R$ given, such that $\int_0^3 f(x)\,dx $ exists.

> Give a function g and a constant C such that $\int_0^3 f(x)dx=C\int_a^b g(x)dx$ while $g$ is only depending on $f$ and $C$ is only depending on $a$ and $b$ .

How does one handle this problem? This task was an old exam question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take $g(x) = \int_0^3f(t)dt$ (yeap, a constant function) and $C = \frac{1}{b-a}$.

Comment: On "how does one handle this": well, your first desire is to say something like $g = f$ but you quickly understand it is wrong, moreover, you understand that almost any reasonable connection to $f$ will fail, cause $g$ should be integrable on any interval, though we have nothing on $f$ outside interval $[0,3]$. So here comes the idea to make $g$ constant. The rest follows.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to switch the $a\to b$ integral to one on $0\to 3$. So let's try

$$\int_a^bg(x)~dx=\int_0^3 g(u)~du$$
Now we need to find the substitution for $u$. When $x=a$ in the first integral we need $u=0$, and when $x=b$ we need $u=3$. So try $u=\frac{3}{b-a}(x-a)$. So we can reverse this to obtain $g$ in terms of $f$. Then the constant $C$ will be to take care of the change of variables, since $du=\frac{3}{b-a}~dx$. I leave it to you to put everything together.